# You don't have write permissions for the /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2 directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rubygems, command-prompt

When I run the following command: `gem update --system`,
I receive the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/share/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2 directory.
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:712:in `verify_gem_home'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:902:in `pre_install_checks'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/installer.rb:302:in `install'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/resolver/specification.rb:104:in `install'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:194:in `block in install'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:182:in `each'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:182:in `install'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:252:in `install'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:246:in `update_gem'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:282:in `update_rubygems'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/commands/update_command.rb:98:in `execute'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command.rb:327:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:252:in `invoke_command'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:192:in `process_args'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/command_manager.rb:150:in `run'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
        /usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/bin/gem:10:in `<main>'
```

When I also try to run `sudo gem update --system --force`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  Your RubyGems was installed trough APT, and upgrading it through RubyGems
itself is unsupported. If you really need the latest version of RubyGems (tip:
you usually don't), then you need to install RubyGems (and Ruby) manually,
maybe using tools like ruby-install, rvm, etc.
```

I have tried reinstalling using:

```bash
sudo \curl -sSl https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable
rvm install 3.2.2
rvm use 3.2.2 --default
```

Comment: Don't use the OS ruby version, use your own locally installed version. As the message suggests use: rvm or rbenv

Comment: Worth checking `which gem` or `gem env` for more details.